# Save all the descriptors taken from multiple images in Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, computer-vision, concatenation, data-analysis

I'm trying to extract the descriptors of multiple images that i have in my database. The method used give me a matrix of keypoints and a matrix of the descriptors for every image, so i want to group them into a sigle matrix.

I've tried over a loop:

```
kp_all = numpy.hstack((kp_all, kp))
des_all = numpy.hstack((des_all, des))
```

where kp_all and des_all are correctlly initialized because is the descriptor of the first image, so i want to concatenate the other descriptors into that matrix. The error given is:

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation 
axis must match exactly
```

The dimensions of the vectors are:

```
Processing image....
dimension kp_all and des_all (10, 7) (10, 32)
Processing image....
dimension kp and des (46, 7) (46, 32)
Processing image....
dimension kp and des (17, 7) (17, 32)
```

anyone has any idea? Thank you!!!

Comment: for doing `hstack` the outer dimensions should match. You've (10, 7) in `kp_all`. So, `kp` should be (10, n)

Comment: maybe i should take the 10 most common points comparing kp with kp_all? It makes sense?

Comment: But it seems from your data, it's better to use `np.vstack` instead. this way you can keep all points. Just replace `hstack` by `vstack`

Comment: yes it works!! i didn't know vstack function. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on OP's comment and observing the dimensions of the variables `kp_all`, `des_all`, `kp`, `des`

> dimension kp_all and des_all (10, 7) (10, 32)
>   dimension kp and des (46, 7) (46, 32)
>   dimension kp and des (17, 7) (17, 32)

We can use, [`np.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)

```
kp_all = np.vstack((kp_all, kp))
des_all = np.vstack((des_all, des))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution... just create an empty list:

```
kp_all = []
des_all = []
```

and append every descriptor in the loop:

```
kp_all.append(kp)
des_all.append(des)
```

Comment: this would be very inefficient for huge sizes.

Comment: Yes, i see. But it's just to store the data to a .txt. If you have any idea, let me know please